# Build the complete Tailwind 3 app.css file using Laravel Mix in Docker container

Tags: webpack, laravel-8, tailwind-css, laravel-mix, laravel-sail

I have set up Laravel in a Docker container and launched it using Laravel Sail. I'm using Laravel mix with tailwind version 3 to include my CSS. The issue is that I want the entire Tailwind CSS to be compiled into my `resources/css/app.css` file.

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.options({
    legacyNodePolyfills: false
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ]);
```

I usually run `./vendor/bin/sail npm run watch` from my application directory within the docker container to compile `resources/css/app.css.` Still, the compilation process takes a while, and the `watch` command doesn't seem to catch any changes and recompile automatically. I guess it is because of my sub-optimal development environment (Intel core i3 and four GB ram).

It seems only Tailwind CSS classes contained in files in the `content` key within `tailwind.config.js` are compiled into `resources/css/app.css` because I have to re-run `./vendor/bin/sail npm run watch` every time I make changes to my blade templates to see changes on my browser, which is cumbersome. Plus, I can't use my web browser (Google Chrome) to inspect CSS and dynamically make changes to see the effect on my browser.

I have already tried removing all files in the `content` key of `tailwind.config.js` i.e. `content: [],` but the resulting `resources/css/app.css` was almost empty; causing tailwind CSS in my blade templates not to work.

Is there a way to modify `tailwind.config.js` or `webpack.mix.js` so I can simply run `./vendor/bin/sail npm run dev` once, and it compiles the entire Tailwind CSS into `resources/css/app.css`? I don't want to include tailwind CSS links in my HTML header.

Answer (score 1):

I also thought my webpack.mix was not working with npm run watch. I would make changes and refresh firefox and the changes did not render as expected.

In my case, I was testing a blade component in Laravel 9 using tailwindcss v3.0.24 on Rocky Linux 8.5 server (nginx, php-fpm, mariadb). With either code snippet below (either worked), I set the background color to bg-orange-500 as the default background color for the component:

```
<div {{ $attributes->class(['text-xl p-4 bg-orange-500']) }}>
```

OR

```
<div {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'text-xl p-4 bg-orange-500']) }}>
```

From the welcome.blade.php where the component is to be rendered, I added background color bg-green-500 to override the default bg-orange-500 as shown in the next snippet.

```
<x-sidebar title="My Sidebar" :info="$info" class="bg-green-500">
```

I expected the orange background color to be overridden by the green on browser refresh. It was not. In my browser, I inspected the background color css markup.

```
<div class="text-xl p-4 bg-orange-500 bg-green-500">
```

I noticed both bg-orange-500 and bg-green-500 in that order.
I expected green to be rendered since it was last in the order. I looked at my freshly recompiled app.css file and found:
class bg-green was on line 443 and class bg-orange was on line 451.
Class bg-orange-500 could not be overridden by bg-green-500 since it is listed on a line further down the the app.css file.

I concluded that mix did not recompile the bg-green-500 on a line further down from bg-orange-500 so that it could actually override it.
I manually moved class bg-green-500 to a line higher than the line class bg-orange-500 was on, saved it, refreshed my browser and bg-green-500 was rendered as expected.
Apparently, mix does not consider that an override class (when working with blade components) should be placed on a line number further down the file than the default class line number.

**What solved this issue for me was to use tailwindcss CDN SCRIPT instead of linking directly to the stylesheet in /public/css/app.css. In my template head section, FOR DEVELOPMENT ONLY, I added the script:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

As soon as I saved the template, all styling rendered properly as expected. The JustInTime CDN script does everything else compiling only the tailwindcss markup you use.

Answer (score 0):

> I usually run `./vendor/bin/sail npm run watch` from my application directory within the docker container to compile resources/css/app.css. Still, the compilation process takes a while, and the watch command doesn't seem to catch any changes and recompile automatically. I guess it is because of my sub-optimal development environment (Intel core i3 and four GB ram).

No, It wasn't my 'sub-optimal' development environment.

According to [Laravel Mix documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#watching-assets-for-changes):

> Webpack may not be able to detect your file changes in certain local development environments.

The same documentation suggests that you run

```
npm run watch-poll
```

instead and It solved the problem of having to run `npm run dev` or `npm run watch` each time I make change to my blade templates.

However, I still have to refresh my browser each time I make changes to my blade templates. The Laravel documentation suggests you use Laravel Mix's `browserSync()` method as shown [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#browsersync-reloading). But it is not applicable in my case, since I'm working from a headless environment i.e. a Docker container. The `browserSync()` method allows you to observe changes in your browser whenever you make changes to your blade template files without having to refresh the browser.

Though, the major problem of generating a complete Tailwind css file so I can inspect elements on my browser and make changes directly on my browser (e.g. through the developer tab in Chrome) haven't been solved yet; I'm now left with only the pain of refreshing my browser each time I want to see changes made to my template files. So, my problem is partially sovled.